# Making chunky calls in .NET versus writing simple and concise methods

Tags: .net, performance, methods

I'm reading "Performance Tips and Tricks in .NET Applications" which is a page of documentation created by Microsoft. One of the tips mentioned in the documentation is to make chunky calls, which are function calls that perform several tasks as opposed to chatty calls which are function calls that perform simple tasks. The rationale is that chatty calls might require multiple calls, whereas you can call a chunky method once and it'll do multiple things.

I was a bit confused on whether or not this is contradictory to the principle that I've been learning regarding writing methods and classes that do one thing very well as opposed to many different things. Is this principle better left to UNIX modules that can be piped into one another? Or should we focus on writing methods and functions that are simple, reusable, and do only one thing really well as opposed to multiple things? If that's the case, then is it a defect to get better performance with chunky calls rather than chatty calls? Or is the principle merely geared towards making code more readable and maintainable rather than highly performant?

The documentation I'm referring to can be found here - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973839.aspx

Best regards,

HandleThatError

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That advice applies specifically to unusually expensive calls,

> It's important to make chunky, rather than chatty calls across methods **where the overhead is higher than for simple, intra-AppDomain method calls.** P/Invoke, interop and remoting calls all carry overhead ...

It still applies. Those things were slow then, they are slow now, and they will be probably slow forever.

It's not a general design guideline, tiny *normal functions* usually get inlined anyway.

Comment: I would argue that they are nowhere near as slow as they used to be... with Gigabit networking as nearly standard, and most cpu's having more modern architectures that have less expensive inter-process and context management costs.  Yes, they're "more expensive" than simple method calls, but I would suspect that unless you're writing a benchmark that tries to get every available cycle out of the software it won't much matter like it did at the dawn of the managed age.

Comment: @ErikFunkenbusch it never really mattered, you cannot have P/Invoke or RPC in high-performance code anyway. By definition it wouldn't be high performance code.

Answer (score 2):

Well, first thing you should notice about that document is that it was written 14 years ago.  The computing landscape, as well as best practice has changed considerably since then.

The second thing you should know is that this article is concerned with eeking out the absolute best performance out of low-level functions.  This is the sort of thing you do only when you have already written a well-designed application and you find that it performs too slowly, and you need to take excessive measures to improve performance.

The third thing you should know is that Hardware and Network performance has increased geometrically since 2001, and in most cases the performance issues talked about simply don't matter anymore when dealing with 4Ghz processors with multiple cores and Gigabytes of memory.

The fourth thing you should know is that the compiler and JIT optimizers have come a long way since .NET version 1, and many of the things talked about in the article either don't apply anymore, or aren't really a factor in most code.

Does the article still apply?  Maybe, in some cases... but you really shouldn't use it as a design inspiration.  As always, design your app correctly, and only optimize when you have profiled your code and found bottlenecks that are actual problems.

Comment: *Hardware and Network performance has increased **geometrically** since 2001* ... shouldn't that be **exponentially**?

Comment: Thanks! Didn't realize it was that old. What if you're trying to scale an application so that it can serve thousands or hundreds of thousands of users? Are higher specs still enough to address those needs? Also, are there any texts or tools on profiling code that you could recommend?

Comment: @HandleThatError - There are two ways to scale, up and out.  Scaling up requires faster or more powerful hardware.  Scaling out requires more hardware.  You should design your system to scale out, which means you just throw more servers at it.  If you do this correctly, you can infinitely scale the problem (assuming the problem lends itself to that, some problems are linear and can't be easily scaled).  I'm not saying you should write poor code, i'm saying you shouldn't prematurely optimize things, and only do "messy" optimizing when absolutely necessary.

Comment: @dubstylee - perhaps, but not always.  I'm more comfortable stating geometric growth.  We hit a lot of plateaus over the last 10 years.

Answer (score 0):

Break things up into small functions because

1. They are stand-alone and unit testable for the most part.
2. They can be reused.
3. Makes the code better to understand if named properly.
4. The compiler can better optimize the release code due to the fewer relations of smaller functions.